# Why does C# null-conditional operator not work with Unity serializable variables?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I've noticed that if I have some variables exposed to the Unity inspector such as:

```
[SerializeField] GameObject _tickIcon;
```

If I leave them unassigned and try to use the null conditional operator and call a method on that object I get an exception saying the variable is not assigned. So basically instead of doing this:

```
_tickIcon?.SetActive(false);
```

It's forcing me to do this:

```
if(_tickIcon != null)
{
   _tickIcon.SetActive(false)
}
```

So I'm guessing this must be something specific to unity's runtime, it's not really null, but I can check for null and it work. I don't really understand this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**It does not work in general with anything inheriting from [`UnityEngine.Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html)!**

tl;dr: The `??` and `?.` operators work on a `System.Object` (aca `object`) level while Unity's `==` operator works on a `UnityEngine.Object` level.

---

Unity has a custom implementation of `==` for `UnityEngine.Object` which actually is a hook down into the underlying `c++` engine. See [Custom == operator, should we keep it?](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it)

ReSharper explained it pretty well in [Possible unintended bypass of lifetime check of underlying Unity engine object](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/wiki/Possible-unintended-bypass-of-lifetime-check-of-underlying-Unity-engine-object)

> This warning is shown if a type deriving from `UnityEngine.Object` uses either the null coalescing (`??`) or null propagation or conditional (`?.`) operators. These operators do not use the custom equality operators declared on `UnityEngine.Object`, and so bypass a check to see if the underlying native Unity engine object has been destroyed. An explicit `null` or boolean comparison, or a call to `System.Object.ReferenceEquals()` is preferred in order to clarify intent.

`UnityEngine.Object` is in some occasions **not really** `null` but still keeps some meta data. So the underlying `object`(= `System.Object`) is **not `null`**, `UnityEngine.Object`'s overwritten `==` operator just returns `true` for `== null`.

The reason for this: The `c#` layer `UnityEngine.Object` is just the developer API layer on top of the actual underlying `c++` engine code. The custom [`==`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/67d5d85abbea076e469a1642e04f3ab50a326bea/Runtime/Export/Scripting/UnityEngineObject.bindings.cs#L506C9-L506C95) and [`implicit bool operator`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/67d5d85abbea076e469a1642e04f3ab50a326bea/Runtime/Export/Scripting/UnityEngineObject.bindings.cs#L115) both basically boil down to

([source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/67d5d85abbea076e469a1642e04f3ab50a326bea/Runtime/Export/Scripting/UnityEngineObject.bindings.cs#L120C1-L131C10))

> ```
>     static bool CompareBaseObjects(UnityEngine.Object lhs, UnityEngine.Object rhs)
>     {
>         bool lhsNull = ((object)lhs) == null;
>         bool rhsNull = ((object)rhs) == null;
>
>         if (rhsNull && lhsNull) return true;
>
>         if (rhsNull) return !IsNativeObjectAlive(lhs);
>         if (lhsNull) return !IsNativeObjectAlive(rhs);
>
>         return lhs.m_InstanceID == rhs.m_InstanceID;
>     }
>    
>     ...
>
>     static bool IsNativeObjectAlive(UnityEngine.Object o)
>     {
>         if (o.GetCachedPtr() != IntPtr.Zero)
>             return true;
>
>         //Ressurection of assets is complicated.
>         //For almost all cases, if you have a c# wrapper for an asset like a material,
>         //if the material gets moved, or deleted, and later placed back, the persistentmanager
>         //will ensure it will come back with the same instanceid.
>         //in this case, we want the old c# wrapper to still "work".
>         //we only support this behaviour in the editor, even though there
>         //are some cases in the player where this could happen too. (when unloading things from assetbundles)
>         //supporting this makes all operator== slow though, so we decided to not support it in the player.
>         //
>         //we have an exception for assets that "are" a c# object, like a MonoBehaviour in a prefab, and a ScriptableObject.
>         //in this case, the asset "is" the c# object,  and you cannot actually pretend
>         //the old wrapper points to the new c# object. this is why we make an exception in the operator==
>         //for this case. If we had a c# wrapper to a persistent monobehaviour, and that one gets
>         //destroyed, and placed back with the same instanceID,  we still will say that the old
>         //c# object is null.
>         if (o is MonoBehaviour || o is ScriptableObject)
>             return false;
>
>         return DoesObjectWithInstanceIDExist(o.GetInstanceID());
>     }
>
>     [NativeMethod(Name = "UnityEngineObjectBindings::DoesObjectWithInstanceIDExist", IsFreeFunction = true, IsThreadSafe = true)]
>     internal extern static bool DoesObjectWithInstanceIDExist(int instanceID);
> ```

background calls into the native engine code where the actual instances of those objects are handled and their lifecycle controlled. So e.g. after `Destroy` an object, in the native `c++` engine the object is already marked as destroyed and the custom `==` and `bool operator` already return `false`. The `c#` layer `UnityEngine.Object` still exists though until it is actually garbage collected (usually at the end of the frame but there is no real guarantee for that either).

The main reason why therefore things like `_tickIcon?.gameObjct` throw a `NullReferenceException` is that the `?.` operator only directly works on the underlying `object`(`System.Object`) while the `UnityEngine.Object` works with their custom implementation on a different level.

E.g. after

```
Destroy(_tickIcon);
_tickIcon.SetActive(false);
```

you will note that you don't get a normal `NullReferenceException` which would be the case if it were actually `null` but rather get a Unity customs `MissingReferenceException` telling you a probable reason for why the exception was thrown.

---

Long story short: As solution `UnityEngine.Object` has the implicit [`bool` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html)

> Does the object exist?

You should **always** check the existence of anything derived from `UnityEngine.Object` like this:

```
if(_tickIcon)
{
    _tickIcon.SetActive(false);
}
```

or explicit (as this will use the custom `==`/`!=` operators)

```
if(_tickIcon != null)
{
    _tickIcon.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the information I was looking for. I was suspecting they had some kind of operator specific implementation but I was not sure. Thanks!

Comment: So optional chaining can't be used for Unity objects? Not allowing a feature of the c# syntax for unity objects is not beneficial to most devs I would think.

Comment: @LoganCundiff yes it can be used .. but it might misbehave ;) Well people complain a lot about Unity and the way things are implemented ... but you forget that actually Unity is all `c++`. The `c#` you are using is just a development layer on top of it to make your live easier .. so I would say it is a tradeoff between still making it work but easy to use .. with some exceptions about some `c#` features ;) The `?` and `??` are basically just shorthands for explicit `null` checks ... you can still use explicit null check if you don't like the implicit bool .. I got used to it

Comment: Thanks for the info! Do you know of a situation in which `?` works with `UnityEngine.Object`?

Comment: @LoganCundiff once the Garbage Collector already collected the object ..then it doesn't make a difference anymore since then the c# instance will actually be a `null` on `System.Object` level ... but there is no reliable time when the GC collects something (except explicitly forcing it)

Answer (score 0):

Just to remix the syntax of this question, when attempting something like this:

```cs
//Error
Vector3 targetPos = target?.position ?? Vector3.zero;
```

Instead try this:

```cs
//OK
Vector3 targetPos = target ? target.position : Vector3.zero;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the destroyed object only returned `true` for the expression `my_obj.Equals(null)` when doing a null check. All the others (e.g. `my_obj == null` or `my_obj is null`) returned `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this asset from the asset store to use the null conditional and null propagation operators safely on GameObjects: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/smooth-operator-271378