# Unity : this == null returns true. How can this happen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working on a project in unity and I'm trying to invoke a function with Invoke(string, float); though I get an error saying to check if my `gameobject` is null, so I tried doing

```
debug.log(gameObject == null);
```

it returned with an error. I tried

```
debug.log(this == null);
```

> result true?

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

```
if(confetti != null)             
{                 
    confetti.Play();             
}             

if (this != null)             
{                 
    StartCoroutine("restart");             
}             
else 
    SceneManager.LoadScene("SampleScene");
```

Answer (score 9):

One unfortunate thing about Unity is that when you do `== null` on a Unity Object, you are not actually just checking for a null reference. For Unity Objects, `== null` will return true if the reference is null OR the object has been destroyed in the scene.

This is an important distinction because Unity Objects actually mostly live "in C++", and the objects you get in C# are mostly just wrappers.

See the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62678228/why-does-c-sharp-null-conditional-operator-not-work-with-unity-serializable-vari)

If you want to just check for a null reference and not if the Unity Object has been destroyed, do one of these:

- Use `is null` / `is not null` syntax
- Cast the  Unity Object into a `System.Object` before doing `== null` check
- Use `object.ReferenceEquals(something, null)`
- Use a null coalescing operator