# This script to increase the Focal Distance of my Depth Of Field override using URP in unity causes unity to freeze with no errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, urp

I tried to create this script which slowly increases the focal distance when a button is pressed(running on start for now) but it causes my unity to freeze with no errors and only way to restart unity is by forcing it to close through task manager.

`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor.Performance.ProfileAnalyzer;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;

public class UnblurBackground : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Volume vol;
    public float fadeRate = 0.01f;
    public float startFocusDistance = 0.1f;
    private float focusDistance = 0.1f;

    DepthOfField dph;

    void Awake()
    {
        //Borrowed from unity forums. Gets the volume component and checks for Depth of Field override.
        VolumeProfile volumeProfile = GetComponent<Volume>()?.profile;
        if (!volumeProfile) throw new System.NullReferenceException(nameof(VolumeProfile));

        if (!volumeProfile.TryGet(out dph)) throw new System.NullReferenceException(nameof(dph));
        //

        //Sets Depth of Field
        dph.focusDistance.Override(0.1f);

        focusDistance = startFocusDistance;
    }

    public void unblur()
    {
        while(focusDistance <= 10)
        {
            //Increases 'focusDistance' variable over time.
            focusDistance += (fadeRate / 1000);
            //Sets depth of field to the 'focusDistance' variable.
            dph.focusDistance.Override(focusDistance);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        unblur();
    }
}
```

`

I have found that if I do not divide the fade rate by 10 it does not crash but it is either fading so quick I can't see it or is simply jumping to 10 instantly.

May be a noob question but I appreciate any assistance. :)
Thanks,
Braith

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```
 VolumeProfile volumeProfile = GetComponent<Volume>()?.profile;
```

should **NOT** be used! See [Why does C# null-conditional operator not work with Unity serializable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62678228/why-does-c-sharp-null-conditional-operator-not-work-with-unity-serializable-vari)

Rather use e.g.

```
if(!TryGetComponent<Volume>(out var volumeComponent))
{
    Debug.LogError($"No {nameof(Volume)} component attached to this object!", this);
    return;
}

var volumeProfile = volume.profile;
```

---

Then in general you do not want any long running `while` loops.

> ```
> //Increases 'focusDistance' variable over time.
> ```

**No it doesn't!**

Currently it is trying to run the entire `while` loop in one single frame .. until it is done it freezes.

---

Currently you need 1 / 0.01 / 1000 / 10 = 1000000 iterations to finish the loop.

I assume what you rather would want to do is a smooth transition using a fixed duration. One of the main tools to achieve this in Unity are [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) like e.g.

```
public float durationInSeconds = 1f;
public float startFocusDistance = 0.1f;
public float targetFocusDistance = 10f;

// If you do this then Start is automatically run as a Coroutine
IEnumerator Start()
{
    for(var timePassed = 0f; timePassed < durationInSeconds; timePassed += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        var factor = timePassed / durationInSeconds;

        dph.focusDistance.Override(Mathf.Lerp(startFocusDistance, targetFocusDistance, factor));

        // basically means "pause" the routine here, render this frame
        // and continue from here in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has fixed all my problems, you are awesome! I really appreciate your help.
Have an amazing day mate.